# Performance issues with `dd` on macOS Sierra?

Tags: linux, macos, sd-card, dd

I'm not sure if I'm the only one having this issue, but when I try to flash out a disk image after upgrading to macOS Sierra, I get *very* bad performance.

When I flash out a disk image using the following command, I get roughly 300-500k write speed:

```
$ unzip -p /path/to/image | pv | sudo dd bs=32m of=/dev/rdisk2
1.31GiB 0:55:37 [ 424KiB/s] [                            <=>    ]
^C
0+4279363 records out
2191033856 bytes transferred in 5218.495041 secs (419859 bytes/sec)
```

The interesting part is if I do the exact same thing inside a VM (Ubuntu 12.04) using the exact same SD card, disk image and USB reader, I get a magnitude faster performance.

```
$ unzip -p /path/to/image | pv | sudo dd bs=32M of=/dev/sdc
3.73GB 0:02:30 [25.4MB/s] [                            <=>    ]
0+55333 records in
0+55333 records out
4004511744 bytes (4.0 GB) copied, 150.572 s, 26.6 MB/s
```

This used to work just fine El Capitan.

I've also tried flashing out using the built-in SD Card reader, but the performance is roughly the same.

Comment: Looking at your logs, the reason for the performance difference is that the first case is using 512-byte records, whereas the the second uses ~72KB records. I'm guessing that the cause of of the difference is the buffer size in `pv`, or possibly the default pipe size in the two implementations. Compare the two commands if you omit `pv` from the pipe, but you will get the best performance if you unzip to a file and copy it as two separate operations, when you'll get the full 32MB buffer. You can monitor the progress by sending `dd` the signal `USR1`, possibly from a background task.

Comment: I can confirm that the behavior stays the same even if I remove the `pv` pipe. I left it running for 30 minutes, without completing. During this time, it merely wrote 330MiB.

Comment: In that case it must be the `bash` default pipe size; so unzip the image, then copy it using something like `dd if=image.iso of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=32M& while kill -USR1 $!; do sleep 30; done`. This gives a progress message every 30 seconds, but you can of course change the `sleep` parameter; it also gives an error when `dd` completes, which you can suppress by redirecting `stderr` on the `kill` command.

Answer (score 1):

Consider testing different block sizes for optimal performance.

Using bs=4096 works for modern thumb drives which are formatted at 4096 block boundaries, while earlier thumb drives use 512.

Additionally use the /dev/rdiskX device.